# What are the steps for solving sec(arctan(-8))?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In the image below you can see how I started out solving the problem. I knew that arctan(-8) would give me an angle measure, so I drew out where tan(x)= -8 would be on the coordinate plane. From there I thought that I could just find sec(x), but then I realized that I do not know the values of y or x. Am I approaching this problem the wrong way? Is there something I'm missing? Is there another way to solve it?  [image: how I attempted to solve the problem]

Comment: You get to choose, lucky you! You could pick $y=8$ and $x=1$, and then Pythagoras gives you the hypotenuse

Comment: Why is it ok to choose whichever values? (I tried y = -8 and x = 1, y = -16 and x =2 and got the same answers)

Comment: For any choice of values, the triangles are similar, so the ratios of two sides are the same. The most common choice is to make the hypotenuse have length 1.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sec(...)$ function is even, it is positive, don't worry about sign of argument.

Draw a right triangle with opposite side length $8$ and adjacent side length $1$. Hypotenuse is $\sqrt{65}$

So $\sec (...)= \sqrt{65}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=1$ and $y=8$. Then $r = \sqrt{65}$ and $\sec(\arctan -8) = \dfrac rx = \cdots$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\forall x\in \mathbb R$

$$\cos(\arctan x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

To prove that we can start from

$$\tan(\arctan x)=x\implies \tan^2(\arctan x)=x^2$$

$$1+ \tan^2(\arctan x)=1+x^2$$

then use that $1+\tan^2y=\frac1{\cos^2y}$.

Comment: How is the identity derived?

Comment: @Hannah, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values to find why the cosine ratio is $$\ge0$$

Comment: @Hannah It is very simple. We have$$ \tan^2 y=\frac{\sin^2 y}{\cos^2 y} \implies  1+\tan^2 y=1+\frac{\sin^2 y}{\cos^2 y}=\frac{\cos^2y + \sin^2 y}{\cos^2 y}=\frac{1}{\cos^2 y}$$